# Xubuntu different boot results, sometimes succeed; most of error: times attempt to read or write outsie of disk hd0

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu

I am really confused, my laptop was fine till three days ago, But after that each time I turn it on, I see different results. These are some of them:

1. sometimes it boots successfully (just like know that I'm asking this question).
2. sometimes it shows error: `attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0`.
3. sometimes it shows 3 errors: 1-`error: font file format error: 1st section must be file`. 2-`error: no suitable video mode found` 3- `attempt to read or write outside of disk "hd0"`
4. shows menu for `Ubuntu` start normally. and a menu for selecting kernels and recovery mod.
5. sometimes it shows me `GNU grub` command line

When I am trying to boot with `DVD live` or `USB live` results will be successful, all the times.

Now my question is what should I do to solve this problem. should I reinstall my `Xubuntu`? Or there is still a chance to save my current OS?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to replace that HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If possible, backup your important files!

Three things to do:

1. Check your disk SMART information

   - boot normally, or to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
   - start the `Disks` application
   - select the disk in the left pane
   - click on the "hamburger" icon
   - select `SMART Data & Tests`
   - review data, look for disk fail/pass messages
   - run tests
2. Lets check your file system for errors

   - boot to the GRUB menu
   - choose Advanced Options
   - choose Recovery mode
   - choose Root access
   - at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
   - repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
   - type `reboot`
3. Run memory tests

   - go to http://memtest86.org and download free memory diagnostic
   - run at least one full pass to test memory

Comment: +1 and with delay approve! I tested the second item (checking file system for errors) and it solved the problem. I'm really not sure why this works. Thanks man :)

Comment: @SirSaleh Do you dual-boot with Windows? Do you have a driver installed on Windows that lets you read Ubuntu partitions? Do you ever mount your Windows C: disk in Ubuntu?

Comment: No! I just have Xubuntu. all other partitions even has `ex4` format.

Comment: @SirSaleh Good. Monitor the SMART data. Backup your important files... just in case. Cheers.

Comment: Yes! Sure :) I am like someone who bitten By Scorpion and have fear to bitten again. Thanks again.